# Always getting "Failed - Network error" when downloading a zip using readFile()

Tags: php, web, readfile

Looking for a bit of help. Ive run in to an issues when downloading a zip file I just created in php.
I seem to always get Network Failed or invalid file. After looking around I came across a few solutions such as trying sending in chunks and `ob_clean(); flush();` but neither worked for me. Am I missing anything important here? I think my header tags are correct. Heres what I got:

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open(($fileloc . "registration/test_new.zip"), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){
        foreach ($_POST["downloaddocs"] as $key => $value) {
            $zip->addFile(($fileloc."registration/allreddocs/".$value),$value);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
        $zipfile = $fileloc . "registration/test_new.zip";
        if (file_exists($zipfile)) {
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfile));
        ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);

} else { 
    print "nofile";
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Network error" looks like unrelated to the output of a php script, maybe some limitations of your webserver/firewall/etc.?